# How to test POST requests with h2load (nghttp2)

Tags: post, server, nghttp2, wrk

I am using h2load (nghttp2) to test a PHP served server. The request type should be POST.

I use the following command, but get the error in server:

```
h2load http://192.168.10.190:8009/echoservice/ping \
  -d post_data \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -t 12 -c 400 -n1000
```

> Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)

The file post_data contains string:

```
msg=FromClient
```

What is the problem with this command?

**UPDATE 1:**

When I use h2load for GET requests, I get `Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)` too! [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) tests are successful. Hence, no problem with server!

In case of [gRPC](https://nghttp2.org/blog/2015/03/27/nghttp2-v0-7-9/), h2load tests were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-H, --header=<HEADER>` option and set `:method` as `POST`.

```
-H: ':method: POST'
```